# Can't delete app because it is suddenly uncompatible

Tags: root-access, uninstallation, samsung-galaxy-mini

I downloaded [SoftkeyEnabler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fatedevgroup.softkeyenabler), but it turned out it wasn't nice for my smaller Samsung Galaxy Mini 2 (CyanogenMod 10.1). So I deleted the app, but the softkeys keep showing up! I tried all kinds of things, but when I look in superuser, active apps etc. It says there is nothing running. When I look at the app in the play store it says that it is not compitable with my device.
What could I do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that you have given admin rights to the app.
reinstall the app and then do this:

Go to SETTINGS->Location and Security-> Device Administrator and deselect the admin.

After this is done, Uninstall the app.

Comment: The problem is that I can't reinstall the app because it is suddenly not compatible anymore.